# parsing pathname in url.pathname()

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, split

I have a url as below

```
localhost:1340/promotionDetails/pwd1/pwd2?promotion_id=PROM008765
```

I used url module for parsing the url for the pathname below is the code

```
var url=require('url').parse('http://localhost:1340/promotionDetails/pwd1/pwd2?  promotion_id=PROM008765', true).pathname
console.log(url);
```

The output that I got is

```
/promotionDetails/pwd1/pwd2
```

I used the split function to get the pwd1 and pwd2 from the path.I want to know if there is anyother way to get pwd1 and pwd2 without using the split function.Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: I think you are not using PHP

Comment: Yes I am not using php

Comment: You can get pwd1 and pwd2 using split easily. What is the harm in that?

Comment: Yes i dont want to use split.Do we have anyother way other than using split?

Answer (score 1):

You can regex to get the url directories without using split.

```
var myurl = "localhost:1340/promotionDetails/pwd1/pwd2?promotion_id=PROM008765";
var match = myurl.match(/[^/?]*[^/?]/g);
/* matches everything between / or ?
[ 'localhost:1340',
  'promotionDetails',
  'pwd1',
  'pwd2',
  'promotion_id=PROM008765' ]
*/
console.log(match[2]);//pwd1
console.log(match[3]);//pwd2
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated 2019 ES6 answer:

You can regex to get the url directories without using split.

```
const myurl = "localhost:1340/promotionDetails/pwd1/pwd2?promotion_id=PROM008765";     
const filteredURL = myurl.match(/[^/?]*[^/?]/g).filter((urlParts) => {
    return urlParts !== 'promotionDetails' && urlParts !== 'localhost:1340'
})

const [pwd1, pwd2] = filteredURL;

console.log(pwd1)
console.log(pwd2)
```